# In MVC5 how do I set the current date and user id in the view for submitting a new object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have an entity that has a userId column from the user table and a submitted date column. When I create a new entity I would like to use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.submitteddate)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubmittedById, User.Identity.GetUserId())
```

have the current date and user id come through
I tried

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.submitteddate, DateTime.Now.ToString())
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubmittedById, User.Identity.GetUserId())
```

but it did not work.

what is the best way to accomplish this?
Is there another way to do it in the view or should I set the variables in the model or controller get or controller post methods?

I'm using mvc5, razor syntax with entity framework 6 and c#

Comment: You should set them in the controller on post. Setting the user ID in a hidden field could cause security issues as the end user would be able to change it before it gets sent back to you

Comment: How would I validate my model though, should I remove the required annotation for these fields on my entity?

Comment: How are you validating your model at the moment?

Comment: I have a System.Datetime column which is require by default and a submitted by string that is required inmy model. In my controller I simply check if (ModelState.IsValid){insert save}

Comment: I would remove the required attributes. You are in control of when the object is saved, you can ensure in your controller that SubmittedDate and SubmittedById are set before the save

Comment: Maybe collect this into an answer @MikeNorgate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting my previous comments into an answer:

Setting the user ID in a hidden field in the HTML will create a security issue as the end user will be able to change the ID, thus impersonating another user.

To avoid this issue set the submitteddate and SubmittedById in your controller after post back. This way you can be certain that the values are set and are correct values.

Comment: You mention that I should not set the user Id in the hidden field but is it okay to have the userid come across in a hidden field upon an edit action?

Comment: You should never make the user ID available in the client in any form that would allow it to be edited. If I managed to get another user's ID I could then make the changes pretending to be someone else

Comment: But then would it be ok to use the userId to link to a user edit page I would assume your going to say no. But then how should I go about doing it, should I use the username to query for a user?